# Response from laravel is not logging properly in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on a project. Where I am using laravel as back end and VueJS as front end. I called an API that requests laravel to insert a user. I want to check whether the back end validation is successfully done or not. for this, I'm sending an email that is already in the database. the validation response is all okay. But I want to log a message only instead of logging the whole response. somehow the message is not logging but the response is logging. I could not figure out what the problem is

**API call**

[image]

**Response**

[image]

I want to log the message, not the whole response

[image]

Comment: Never add code or error messages as images, please. They can't be copy/pasted to work with them, users relying on screen readers can't access them, and they might be blocked. Please edit your question and replace all image content with text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1288408

Answer (score 0):

So the 422 is an error you will have to handle it in a `.catch` block

```
.then() // everything went good
.catch() // something went wrong
```

Something like this

```
.then(response => {
    // great
})
.catch(error => {
    if (error.response.status === 422) {
    // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: 422 is an error that is catched in response variable.

Comment: Your `then` will not run on a 422, only the error, the console is telling you that there was an uncaught error, You need to use the .catch

Comment: Error the same?

Comment: Code looks like it will handle correctly, so maybe a caching issue or similar causing the browser to not run the latest code.

Comment: if i don't log the response, the response is automatically get logged

Answer (score 0):

Chain the ```.catch(error => { console.log("Errors, error") }); on your ajax request.

I have written this small helper once. It can handle Laravel and also your custom messages returned from the backend. It's not perfect but can get your working in a good direction.

```
export function errorMessage(error) {
    let errorResponse = error.response.data.errors ? error.response.data.errors : error.response.data;

    let errors = [];
    for (let key in errorResponse){
        if(key === 'message'){
            errors.push(errorResponse[key]);
        }
        else if (key !== 'exception' && key !== 'file' && key !== 'line' && key !== 'trace'){
            for (let i = 0; i < errorResponse[key].length; i++){
                errors.push(errorResponse[key][i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return errors;
}
```

You can use it in your catch block like `let errors = errorMessage(error))`. I fed my notification plugin with messages that displays on the top of the screen.

Comment: if i don't log the response, the response is automatically get logged